# Adding cent os user by editing configuration file

Tags: linux, shell, configuration, terminal, centos

Im using cent os 6 for my work. For educational purposes I want to add user to the cent os by only editing configuration files.I know we can easly add user by **useradd** command and change their password using **passwd** command. But I need to use exactly above mentioned way. To do this first I need to understand what are the files I have to change

By searching I found that following files are responsible for handling user

```
/etc/passwd
/etc/group
/etc/shadow
/etc/gshadow
```

What I did is first I add the user using **useradd** command and then study the strings that commands created in above files. And then I try to replicate it with manually editing files using VI editor. After I replicate every line of string I make a directory for my new user in **/home**. the I reboot the VM and try to login as manually created user. I can log in without any problems but the terminal showing **bash-4.1$** instead of my username. but when I use **whoami** terminal prints my username correctly.

My question are 
Is there any other files do I need to modify to add user successfully?
By adding user manually what are the functionalities that user lost ?
How to create MD5 hashed password for manually created user ?

I know to you this is may be little bit odd. but I need to do this exactly this way. If this question is inappropriate please let me know without down voting

thanks

Comment: this may be more relevant in serverfault, but maybe not... it's kind of a low level posix adherence question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are the essentials, obviously you'll need to create a home directory for that user with proper permissions, as well as any additional user specific resources.

You might want to also read up on the Pluggable Authentication Module or PAM.  This provides increased authentication functionality to Linux beyond passwd, group, shadow files.

Also check out the GETPWNAM() system call.

=D  Enjoy the Posix!

Serverfault on password hash creation below.

REF:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81240/manually-generate-password-for-etc-shadow